# Subfigure with different image size

Tags: graphics, subfloats, includegraphics

I have two images with size of 1920 by 1280 and 561 by 422. I want to include them in a figure. But due to different sizes, the resulting figure is not looking good.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[!t]
    \centering
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Results/image_10.jpg}%
    \label{fig_msg_img}}
    \hfil
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Results/Untouched_Frame_351.png}
    \label{fig_frame_351}}
    \caption{\protect\subref{fig_msg_img} The message image and \protect\subref{fig_frame_351} a frame from the video.}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

I want the images to have the same height. So, I tried to get the desired result by stating a constant height like this `\includegraphics[height=2in]{Results/image_10.jpg}` for both images. But yet the result was not as expected. The output was

[image: output 2]

How may I get the figure having both the images the same size (maintaining aspect ratio is not necessary)?

The images can be found here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYGeL.jpg and https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCJGW.jpg

Comment: Your images should have equal width regardles the they natural width is noooot equal. SInce thex havent means, tha secon one has arounf it white space. To see it, insert it in `\fbox` : `\subfloat[]{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Results/Untouched_Frame_351.png}}`. Remove tis white space by some tool for editing images.

Comment: @Mico, just conclude. From code follows, that  both image are scaled to equal width. If the not appear width  equal width, means that one image has some white space around it (before/after at least). Is  my reasoning wrong? OP probably shod define equal heights for both images too.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks. Removing the white space worked fine.

Comment: @Zarko - Sorry, I deleted my initial comment since I decided to post a full answer. Indeed, the second image has a massive white frame, which is causing the problems.

Comment: @Mico, it is OK.  I didn't check OP images (I don't like browsing for images or codes). Your answer is fine and educative (+)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you've encountered has nothing to do with LaTeX *per se*. Instead, it's caused by the second image file coming with a considerable white "frame" around the actual image.

I suggest you use a suitable graphics tool to remove the frame. Once you do that, you'll end up getting something like the following. (Since your document has two main columns on each page, I would also like to recommend that you choose`width=\columnwidth` rather than `width=0.45\textwidth`.)

[image]

If, in addition, you could get the aspect ratios of the two images to be the same, I'd definitely pursue that route as well.

```
\documentclass[journal,times]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*} % "[t!]" has no effect on a double-wide float
   %\centering
   \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{pic1}%
      \label{fig_msg_img}}
   \hfill
   \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{pic2}% %  <-- don't forget the '%' symbol
      \label{fig_frame_351}}
   \caption{\protect\subref{fig_msg_img} The message image.
            \protect\subref{fig_frame_351} A frame from the video.}
   \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation regarding the use `\columnwidth`. It made the document better looking.

Comment: What does the `times` option in the `\documentclass` do?

Comment: @imran - the option tells LaTeX to use a clone of the Times Roman text font.